# How to count number of Items in RadListbox at client side

Tags: telerik

I want to check number of items in **RedListbox** at Client side.

How can i do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved myself by using following code at client side.

```
 var list = $find("<%= listbox_InitialSelected.ClientID %>");
    var count = list.get_items().get_count();
```